# Transaction failed on even transaction index solidity, double function call with one form submit

Tags: solidity, metamask, react, failed-transaction

I try to push data into two struct with single call on front end app, it turns out the data that i push on even index of transaction failed on second struct

[image: Transaction History]
[image]

### Struct

```
struct MakananPart1{
        uint kodeProduksi1;
        string nama;
        string deskripsi;
        address produsen;
        uint berat;
    }
    struct MakananPart2{
        uint kodeProduksi2;
        uint harga;
        bool halal;
        uint tglProduksi;
        uint tglKadaluwarsa;
        bool status;
        string komposisi;
    }
```

### creation function

```
function createMakananPart1(
        uint _kodeProduksi,
        string memory _nama,
        string memory _deskripsi,
        uint _berat) public {
            require(bytes(_nama).length > 0);
            require(bytes(_deskripsi).length > 0);
            require(_berat > 0);
            require(_kodeProduksi > 0);
            makananCount++;


            makananPart1s[makananCount] = MakananPart1(
                _kodeProduksi,
                _nama,
                _deskripsi,
                msg.sender,
                _berat
            );

            emit MakananPart1Created(
                _kodeProduksi,
                _nama, 
                _deskripsi, 
                msg.sender, 
                _berat);

            // makananCount--;
        }

    function createMakananPart2(
        uint _kodeProduksi,
        uint _harga,
        uint _tglProduksi,
        uint _tglKadaluwarsa,
        string memory _komposisi
    ) public {
        require(_harga > 0);
        require(_tglProduksi > 0);
        require(_tglKadaluwarsa > 0);
        require(bytes(_komposisi).length > 0);
        require(_kodeProduksi > 0);

        // makananCount++;

        makananPart2s[makananCount] = MakananPart2(
            _kodeProduksi,
            _harga,
            true,
            _tglProduksi,
            _tglKadaluwarsa,
            false,
            _komposisi
        );

        emit MakananPart2Created(
            _kodeProduksi,
            _harga,
            true,
            _tglProduksi,
            _tglKadaluwarsa,
            false,
            _komposisi
        );
    }
```

### function call

```
<form
          onSubmit={(event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            let kodeProduksi = this.props.kodeProduksi;
            kodeProduksi++;
            const nama = this.makananNama.value;
            const deskripsi = this.makananDeskripsi.value;
            const berat = this.makananBerat.value;

            const harga = this.makananHarga.value;
            const tanggal_produksi = this.makananproduksi.value;
            const tanggal_kadaluwarsa = this.makananKadaluwarsa.value;
            const komposisi = this.makananKomposisi.value;

            this.props.createMakananPart1(kodeProduksi, nama, deskripsi, berat);
            this.props.createMakananPart2(
              kodeProduksi,
              harga,
              tanggal_produksi,
              tanggal_kadaluwarsa,
              komposisi
            );
          }}
        >
```